# runtime check failure in using sprintf_s in C

Tags: c

I want to concatenate a string by using 'sprintf()' but I get a runtime check failure (stack around the variable 'szBuffer1' was corrupted).

```
void main()
{
    char szBuffer1[128] = { 0 };
    char szBuffer2[16] = { 0 };

    gets_s(szBuffer1, sizeof(szBuffer1));
    gets_s(szBuffer2, sizeof(szBuffer2));

    sprintf_s(szBuffer1 + strlen(szBuffer1), sizeof(szBuffer1), "%s", szBuffer2);

    puts(szBuffer1);
    printf("%d", strlen(szBuffer1));


}
```

I thought it was a stack overflow problem, so I increased the memory size of 'szBuffer1' from 64 to 128, but it didn't work.

Comment: It is intentional, sprintf_s() ensures you get this runtime error when you pass incorrect arguments in the Debug configuration.  sizeof(szBuffer1) is wrong, the remaining space is sizeof(szBuffer1) - strlen(szBuffer1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given input:

```
Hello
```

The statement:

```
sprintf_s(szBuffer1 + strlen(szBuffer1), sizeof(szBuffer1), "%s", szBuffer2);
```

will be equivalent to:

```
sprintf_s (szBuffer1 + 5, 128, "%s", szBuffer2);
```

But the remaining bytes left in the buffer are `128 - 5`, not `128`. Change it to:

```
const size_t len = strlen (szBuffer1);
sprintf_s (szBuffer1 + len, sizeof szBuffer1 - len, "%s", szBuffer2);
```

---

*Sidenote:* `sprintf_s` returns the number of bytes written. Use its return value in the call to `printf()` instead of calling `strlen()` like so:

```
const int size = sprintf_s (szBuffer1 + len, sizeof szBuffer1 - len, "%s", szBuffer2);
printf ("%d\n", len + n);
```